# Java passing generic class with parameterzied enum as parameter to another generic object

Tags: java, generics, enums, parameterization

I am trying to implement parameterized class in Java with enum as a type parameter. Everything works fine, except, if you look at the code below, there is that anonymous class `Car.Creator` with parameter `K`. But of course, instead of `K`, there should be `CarObject<T>`, but it's not that easy. If I put `CarObject<T>` in `K`'s place, then I got syntax error. Could someone explain if something like this is possible and maybe provide with some code sample.

```
public class CarObject<T extends Enum<T>>
{
  public Map<T, String> values;
  private Class<T> typeClass;

  public CarObject(Class<T> clazz)
  {
    typeClass = clazz;
    values = new EnumMap<T,String>(typeClass);
  }


  public static final Car.Creator<K> Creator = new Car.Creator<K>()
  {
    public K create()
    {
      return new K();
    }


    public K[] newArray(int size)
    {
      return new K[size];
    }
  }
}
```

I can give you an example from official [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)(look at the code in 'Class Overview') where this works perfectly fine. I think there is some magic going on under the hood in Android. I'm trying to do exactly the same thing - implement Parcelable interface. I just made up this example without `implements Parcelable` and other stuff, because I though maybe it's just a syntax sugar :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Android expert, but I'm pretty sure there's nothing magic about how this is happening in Android.  I think you're just confused about the relationship between generic type arguments and statics.

Generic type arguments (like `T` in your example) belong to the *instances* of the class, not to the class itself.

Static members (like `Creator` in your example) belong to *the class itself*, not to the instances of the class.

The fact that `Creator` is an anonymous inner class implementing a generic interface is a bit of a red herring here.  The issue is simply that, *regardless of what `Creator` is*, as long as it is `static`, it can't access the type `T`.

Comment: I think that in Android this particular object must be `static`. From the Android docs: "Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a static field called CREATOR, which is an object implementing the Parcelable.Creator interface."

Comment: So then, the final question is - if there exists any other way how to pass this class with generic type to the `Creator`?

Comment: @janisg: I think that means that classes that implement `Parcelable` cannot be generic.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the `Parcelable` interface to help you out further.  Perhaps you should create a new, more specific question, since you're out of the realm of Java and generics now.

Answer (score 1):

Make the method non-static as per the compiler message, but you have several other major design problems anyway. create() needs a clazz from somewhere, and you can't return generic arrays.

**EDIT** I don't normally post code solutions but you seem pretty confused.

```
public class CarObject<T extends Enum<T>>
{

    public Map<T, String> values;
    private Class<T> typeClass;

    public CarObject(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        typeClass = clazz;
        values = new EnumMap<T, String>(typeClass);
    }
    public final Car.Creator<CarObject<T>> Creator = new Car.Creator<CarObject<T>>()
    {

        @Override
        public CarObject<T> create()
        {
            return new CarObject<T>(typeClass);
        }

        @Override
        public CarObject<T>[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new CarObject[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes I can return `new K()`, because I have working code for that with basic non parametric class - when instead of `K` there is `CarObject` without parameter, for example.

Comment: @janisg No you can't. The compiler says so. You can return `new CarObject<T>(typeClass);`. Not the same thing.

Comment: I can give you an example from official [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)(look at the code in 'Class Overview') where this works perfectly fine. I think there is some magic going on under the hood in Android. I'm trying to do exactly the same thing here - implement Parcelable interface. I just made up this example, because I though maybe it's just a syntax sugar :).

Comment: @janisg: If `K` is a **concrete type**, then yes you can (that's what it is in the Android example).  If `K` is a **generic type parameter**, then no you can't.

Comment: If `K` is `CarObject` then it's OK and if `K` is `CarObject<T>` it won't work? Right?

Comment: @janisg: Are you saying that you literally type `public static final Car.Creator<CarObject> Creator = new Car.Creator<CarObject>()`?  Then yes, that will "work", but it won't do what you want, because you'll be using the *raw type* of `CarObject`, and the type `T` will be erased there as well.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to tell. Is there any hack how to circumvent this and trick the correct type in?

Comment: @janisg: What would "the correct type" be?  `Creator` is a **static member** of the **class itself**, where there is no `T` parameter to use! See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following statement -

```
public static final Car.Creator<K> Creator = new Car.Creator<K>() {
    public K create() {
        return new K();
    }
    public K[] newArray(int size) {
        return new K[size];
    }
}; // <------ missing a semicolon here
```

Looks like you have a **generic** class Creator defined as **static inner** class in the class Car. And, here your trying to use it and instantiate it, so can not use **K** here unless it's a class or an interface defined somewhere.

I think the following example explains what I mean -

```
// you are not defining a class here so no parameter instead use a real class
public static final List<K> list = new List<K>() { /*....*/ };
```

Comment: As I mentioned already, `K` is just the placeholder for this example. I want to put `CarObject<T>` in palce of `K`.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, but `K` is there just to illustrate the location in code where I want to place `CarObject<T>`.

Comment: @janisg: Because you used the `static` modifier, the `Creator` object is a static member of the `CarObject` class, not of any specific *instantiation* of `CarObject`.  So it can be accessed as `CarObject.Creator`.  As such, it doesn't have any access to the `T` type variable, which only has a value for specific concrete instantiations of `CarObject` like `CarObject<SomeSpecificEnum>`.  You can either have a creator that can create `CarObject<SomeSpecificEnum>`s, or a creator that is static, but not both.